# Search for the most recently added node

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm adding vertices with a certain label to a graph (currently using gremlin-python over gremlinv3.3). I'm manually adding a "timestamp" property to these nodes. I want to be able to find the most recently added vertex with this label so that I can then retrieve a certain number of vertices backwards down the chain from there. Adding a set of a "next" type edges from the second-newest to the newest vertex at each addition will allow me to perform the backwards search once I've found the newest vertex.
I want to be able to locate the most recently added vertex in sub-linear time (ideally O(1) time). Here are a couple of ideas how to do that:

- I could manually maintain a node of type "newest" which points to the
  newest vertex of this type and then search for that.
- I could create a binary tree of index vertices over these vertices as I add them, so that searching up the tree and back down from any
  of these vertices delivers me to the newest node in O(log(n)) time.
- It may also be that I could exploit the timestamp property to search efficiently, but it's not clear to me how.

The problem is, I don't know enough about how the graph search is implemented under the hood to know which of these strategies is best. Can anyone help? 
It's also likely that what I create will get redeployed in an amazon-neptune instance, and again, it's not clear to me whether that would change the best strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could manually maintain a node of type "newest" which points to the
>   newest vertex of this type and then search for that.

That's the simplest and fastest solution. Solutions based on other search queries require some kind of index structure that will not allow you to access the latest vertex in `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks, but after all, I'm not sure this is the right solution. I found out about the profile() step, which allows me to test execution time.
`g.g.addV('test').next()
for x in range(10000):
 g.g.addV('other').next()
 if x % 100 == 0:
  print(g.g.V().hasLabel('test').profile().next()['@value']['dur'])
`
This test shows the duration of the query increasing as the content (number of vertices) increases. If, however, I know the id of the vertex I'm looking for, then the query executes in O(1) time. This suggests that I should keep the id of the most recent node outside of the graph(?)

Comment: That's considered an anti-pattern. Perhaps just index the test vertex on a dummy property.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that you could create indexes - that's a game changer. In fact, this section of the documentation suggests that I can't, at least with Tinkerpop3: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/reference/#_indices, but this sections suggests that I should be able to: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/reference/#security ... with gremlin-python attached to Tinkerpop3, I don't seem to be able to access a createIndex or createKeyIndex method - any suggestions?

Comment: I was just reminded that Neptune indexes everything automatically. Hence a query like `g.V().has('test', 'foo', 'bar')` should always perform well.